# CK Editor Default font family and font size

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

How to change the default font family and font size of `CK Editor`.

- By default i need to set my font family and font size.

I tried with this,

```
config.font_defaultLabel = 'Georgia';
config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '20';
```

By this I'm able to change only the dropdown value, but style not applied in `CK Editor` editable area.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise editor's skin to adapt ti for your needs. More information about you can find here: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/skin_sdk_intro.html

Another option is to use [divarea](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/divarea) type editor. Editor with this plugin doesn't create iframe, but creates regular div instead. This will result, that editor's content will inheritance css rules from your main page.